# R: Show plot when running script from command line

Tags: r, ggplot2, command-line, graphics

How to display a window with a ggplot figure when executing an R script from the command line (without intermediary save to file)?

Example script `test.R`

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length), data = iris) + geom_histogram(color = 'black', fill = NA)
plot(p)
```

On the command line run the script with `./test.R`.
This dumps the plot to Rplots.pdf - instead I'd like a window just like in an interactive session with the plot, with no file output.

How to specify output device to be the screen? (e.g. on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this via a call to `X11()`, which will open a graphics window. Some relevant excerpts from `help("X11")`:

> on Unix-alikes ‘X11’ starts a graphics device driver for the X
>             Window System (version 11).  This can only be done on
>             machines/accounts that have access to an X server.
>
> Usage:
>
> X11(display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg, canvas,
>            fonts, family, xpos, ypos, title, type, antialias)
>
> Arguments:
>
> display: the display on which the graphics window will appear.  The
>             default is to use the value in the user's environment
>             variable ‘DISPLAY’.  This is ignored (with a warning) if an
>             X11 device is already open on another display.

However, it will close immediately after the R script is done being executed. So, this works to display your plot, but it isn't open for long:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length), data = iris) +
    geom_histogram(color = 'black', fill = NA)
X11()
plot(p)
```

I guess the real questions are

- Why are you averse to saving the plot before viewing it? and
- If you want to open a plot window but not save the plot, why not just run your commands in an interactive R session? That seems to me more useful if you're not saving results.

Comment: Yes, you are right - this does flash the window, but its too quick to be usable. Is there a way to detach the display process so that it stays open until I close it manually?

Comment: Concerning your questions - I definitely could for example dump the plot into png, wrap the R script with a shell script and open the png. I thought there might be a more elegant way. It's a quick calculation script that I just want to fire off, have a look and close. I don't need the plot for posteriority and opening an interactive R session is more keystrokes. Nonetheless, if there is no easy way to detach the X11 window, then I'll just do it through a png...

Comment: You could `Sys.sleep(Inf)` and just ctrl-c when you're done looking at the graph.